# svchost.exe_Audiosrv crashes randomly

Tags: windows-10, audio, crash, svchost

svchost.exe_Audiosrv crashes at random times (only while listening to youtube videos it seems). There is no error message, but I lose audio. The computer seems to think that no audio device is avalaible. Simply restarting my computer fixes this, but it gets annoying since this happens a few times a month.

I've tried to reinstal the audio related drivers, but this continues to happen. Right-clicking on the audio symbol and choosing to debug audio problems sometimes proposes to restart the computer, or just doesn't find anything. I checked in the fiability history, here's what was written:

---

Source

Host Process for Windows Services

*Summary*

Stopped responding and was closed

Date

‎2020-‎12-‎06 13:56

Statut

*Report sent*

Description
A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.

*Problematic application path* :    C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

*Problem signature*

*Event name* :  AppHangXProcB1

Application Name:   svchost.exe_Audiosrv

Application Version:    10.0.19041.546

Application Timestamp:  058e175a

Hang Signature: fb6f

Hang Type:  64

Waiting on Application Name:    audiodg.exe

Waiting on Application Version: 10.0.19041.546

*SE version*:   10.0.19041.2.0.0.768.101

*regional parameters ID*:   3084

Additional Hang Signature 1:    fb6fa03074cf9317d96fcf3d9dae46e8

Additional Hang Signature 2:    2800

Additional Hang Signature 3:    2800a892444b5ab995aa1a7b236246b3

Additional Hang Signature 4:    fb6f

Additional Hang Signature 5:    fb6fa03074cf9317d96fcf3d9dae46e8

Additional Hang Signature 6:    2800

Additional Hang Signature 7:    2800a892444b5ab995aa1a7b236246b3

*Complementary information on the problem*

*compartiment identification* : b09a8d17a1ebda78bda8d0202397914a (2137186859641966922)

---

Italic text was manually translated from french to english
Also, sorry for the errors in my text, english is my second language.
Thank you to everyone who would have ideas to fix this!

Operating system: windows 10 family version 2004
Acer Aspire A515-54